# Subtract two dataset values and save it in a new column

Tags: c#, string, parsing, int, dataset

I have a small problem according to data set values, I want to subtract those values and save it a new variable column, this is my code:

```
StrSQL = "Select * from Stocks";
 rs = (DataSet) MethodClass.ConnectionToQuery(StrSQL);
for (i = 0; i < rs.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
StrSQL = " Update Stocks Set ";

// Error is in below line 
 StrSQL = StrSQL + " Balance = '" + (rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RQty"]) - (rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["IQty"]) + "'";

StrSQL = StrSQL + " Where ProductCode = '" + rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProductCode"] + "'";
MethodClass.ConnectionToQueryCommand(StrSQL, "ExecuteNonQuery");
}
```

Error is:

> Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'object'

Comment: Have you ever read your error message? As it said, you can't use `-` operator between `string` and `object`. Both `rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RQty"]` and `rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["IQty"]` returns `object`.

Comment: yes, i read, but system accepts first value as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume, that quantity is a integer value.
you have to parse the values as integer to be able to calculate with them

replace

```
StrSQL = StrSQL + " Balance = '" + (rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RQty"]) - (rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["IQty"]) + "'";
```

with

```
int Value1 = int.Parse(rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RQty"]);
int Value2 = int.Parse(rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["IQty"]);
int Result = Value1  - Value2 ;
StrSQL = StrSQL + " Balance = '" + Result  + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StrSQL = StrSQL + " Balance = '" + (Convert.ToDecimal(rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RQty"])) - (Convert.ToDecimal(rs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["IQty"])) + "'";
```

Comment: @SonerGönül Ideally quantity should be a decimal value.

Comment: all values are integer

Comment: @MaroofQaiser use Convert.ToInt32 instead

Comment: @prashanth , i have used it , but the system accepts first value as a string, then it  shows error like Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'